# my phonegap application looks smaller in Android HD phones, HDPI and XHDPI phones

Tags: android, html, cordova

i am newbie, developing an hybrid application using phonegap & jquery mobile. my application looks fine in mdpi devices. But, the application UI looks smaller/shrinks in HDPI & XHDPI phones,tablets & Apple devices.

Currently am using the viewport meta tag as

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

how can i acheieve the same UI in all screen resolutions & DPIs.

Need your suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Remove target-densityDpi=device-dpi.  Basically this is all you need:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
```

Comment: if a remove device-dpi, it takes mdpi as default value & looks fine in mdpi device. but in hdpi and xhdpi screens, it looks ok. i have to make changes in css to support other DPIs.. IS it the right approach to target all android and ios devices??

Comment: Yes, target-densitydpi is being deprecated in most browser.  For the most part, it's fine.  Popular practice is to use media query on the link tag to provide override for different device resolution and device-pixel-ratio.  And if you truly need to support highres, see: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/